# Обновление пользовательского элемента управления при изменении свойства

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Было необходимо написать пользовательский элемент управления бинарное дерево на C#.
Вот что получилось:

```
public partial class UserControl1: UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        localTree = new myTree();
    }

    [EditorAttribute(typeof(myEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]

    //Единственное добавленное свойство
    public myTree result
    {
        get { return localTree; }
        set
        {
            localTree = value;
            this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            localTree.print(this.treeView1);
            this.treeView1.Update();
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
    private myTree localTree;
}
```

+Есть класс самого бинарного дерева+класс его узлов, не буду приводить, потому что он простой и в нем нет ошибок

```
public class myTree
{
    myNode root;
    public myTree() { }
    public string Add(int x)
    {
        if (root == null) { root = new myNode(x); return "0"; }
        else { return "0" + root.Add(x); }
    }

    public void print(TreeView tv) 
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            tv.Nodes.Add(Convert.ToString(root.x));
            root.print(tv.Nodes[0].Nodes);
        }
    }
}
```

и еще есть редактор:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class myEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    myEditor() { }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        IWindowsFormsEditorService edSvc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));
        if (edSvc == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        using (EditFormBinaryTree form = new EditFormBinaryTree(value as myTree))
        {
            if (edSvc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return form.getTree();
            }
        }

        // If OK was not pressed, return the original value
        return value;
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что уже при тестировании, если я изменю значение свойства result(т.е. изменю дерево), изменения сохраняются в локальной переменной дерева, но изменения не отображаются в treeView, который расположен у меня на контроле.
У меня есть подозрение, что это должно происходить как раз-таки в сеттере моего свойства

```
public myTree result
{
    get { return localTree; }
    set
    {
        localTree = value;
        this.treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        localTree.print(this.treeView1);
        this.treeView1.Update();
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Пробовала подписываться на различные события : `onPaint` и пр., но безрезультатно
Помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: Хм. Это у вас WinForms, что ли?

Comment: Да, именно они

Comment: @lester: Ох, занесла же вас нелёгкая пользоваться фреймворком каменного века! Сколько-нибудь сложные вещи лучше делать на WPF.

Ну да ладно. Попробуйте расставить breakpoint'ы: вызывается ли нужный setter вообще?

Comment: Неет... Как такое может быть?? Ну надо же...

Comment: ДААААА, все заработало, после того, как я добавила метод copy для дерева. И в сеттер теперь заходит, и отображается все теперь! Большое спасибо за помощь, я бы очень нескоро это бы сама исправила
С самого начала в принципе казалось логичным сделать метод для копирования дерева, но захотелось пойти легкими путями. Вот уж никогда бы не догадалась, что это может так повлиять на сеттер. Спасибо, буду внимательнее изучать мануалы

Comment: @lester: Вот и хорошо. Тогда перекину в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setter не будет вызываться: на редактирование уходит не копия `myTree`, а оригинал, вы ведь отдаёте ссылку на него.

Встраивайте доп. логику в другое место.